# How to extend a jQuery selector that is stored in a variable?

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

I have a jQuery selector stored in a variable, like so:

```
var myVariable = $( ".js-selector" );
```

I'm wondering if and how I can use this variable to select children of this element, instead of writing:

```
$( ".js-selector .some-child" );
```

How do I do this?

I'm also wondering if I gain some performance benefits from using the cached selector even if I'm extending it with some other selectors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) on the object return by jQuery to get the descendants of the object you have in variable.

```
var descendants = myVariable.find(".some-child");
```

There is one more syntax which could be use by passing context with selector [jQuery( selector [, context ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1). Although this is converted to a find call so better to use the above one.

```
var descendants = $(".some-child", myVariable);
```

Using the cashed object will give you better performance but it might be very little to notice it. You can use this [jspref](http://jsperf.com/) website to compare performance.

[Live performance test on jspref](http://jsperf.com/perf-selector-using-parent-as-reference)

I have made live jspref test for comparing the selector performance using parent as object and using parent in selector. This test shows the first method you have where parent descendant selector is around 28 percent slower then if we first get the parent in object and use find to get descendants.

Comment: Thanks! Also, if someone knows about performance benefits, please do answer! :)

Comment: I ran a test on jspref now. Using the partially cached selector was 14% faster than writing out entire selector. Just interesting to know.